# How to write a driver for Hokuyo Laser Scanner?

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, hector-slam, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a driver for laser scanner and publish data on /scan topic.
I write this code for initializing:

```
    sensor_msgs::LaserScan laser_data;
    laser_data.header.frame_id="laser";
    laser_data.angle_max=((210.234375)/180)*M_PI;
    laser_data.angle_min=((-29.53125)/180)*M_PI;
    laser_data.angle_increment=(0.3515625/180)*M_PI;
    laser_data.header.stamp=ros::Time::now();
    laser_data.scan_time=0.10000000149;
    laser_data.time_increment=9.76562732831e-05;
    laser_data.range_min=0.019999999553;
    laser_data.range_max=5.59999990463;
    laser_data.ranges.resize(682);
```

and put my data on ranges array.

I can see laser data in Rviz but when i used it for hector_slam , It's not worked and I saw this error:

> [ INFO] [1395750671.645863427]:
> lookupTransform base_link to laser
> timed out. Could not transform laser
> scan into base_frame.
>
> [ERROR] [1395750671.815635459]:
> Trajectory Server: Transform from /map
> to scanmatcher_frame failed: "map"
> passed to lookupTransform argument
> target_frame does not exist

another warning that i saw in Rviz in Global Status box is :

> No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame
> [laser] does not exist

This is my tf_tree when run hector_slam:

[image: image description]

When i try with urg_node , hector_slam worked correctly.
This is the tf tree with urg_node:

[image: image description]

I used a Hokuyo 04LX laser scanner.

Does anyone has any suggestion about this problem?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144006/how-to-write-a-driver-for-hokuyo-laser-scanner?/) by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-25**:
This sounds more like a TF problem than an implementation problem of your driver. Investigate your TF tree and so on.

**Comment by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) on 2014-03-27**:
Is the TF broadcaster "/base_to_laser_broadcaster" the same in both cases? Is it a tf static_transform_publisher or a node you wrote yourself? Can you try to increase the publish rate for /base_to_laser_broadcaster?

**Comment by [MiNiBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/25095/minibot/) on 2015-11-14**:
I also got problem like this. Is there anyone can solve this? Thank a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´d suspect that the frame_id you use is different from the one used when using the hokuyo_driver, as the transform error says that there is no connection from the laser to the base_frame. If you´re sure you didn´t change any other parts of your robot system, doing a "rostopic echo" on your scans and comparing the output for both the hokuyo_driver and your own driver should show you the difference (if any). If at all possible, I´d suggest using the existing driver however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) on 2014-03-26**:
I checked "rostopic echo" but there is no difference between my program and urg_node.

yes ,you're right.i should use existing drivers but in my situation i think i don't have another choice.

**Comment by [mr.karimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9676/mr.karimi/) on 2014-03-26**:
I want to connect the laser scanner to an embedded board that doesn't have ros and send laser  data through udp.
I have another program in ROS that receive udp data and publish as LaserScan topic.